# Spring PropertyResourceConfigurer support for Bonecp DataSource

Tags: spring

I need to set the BoneCp driverProperties using Spring `PropertyResourceConfigurer`  (`setDriverProperties(Properties driverProperties)`. `setDriverPropertie` accepts `java.util.Properties` where I could pass the list of properties as key/values. Currently I am loading the DS using the applicationContext.xml with the help of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>
```

I am not sure how I can pass alist of custom properties using applicationContext.xml where `BoneCPDataSource` property name would be `driverProperties` which would be accepting `java.util.Properties`.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://jolbox.com/configuration-spring.html) of BoneCP. Also simply adding  a `<props>` element allows you to specify `Properties` object. Or add a `PropertiesFactoryBean` (or `util:properties` element) to load a properties file and make that available as `Properties` object.

Comment: Thanks Deinum, Would check this out....